# How to use a global for my render window

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a global assigned as a pointer to my window like this:

`globals.cpp & globals.h` has:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
sf::RenderWindow* window
```

Then in `main.cpp` i put:

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#include "globals.h"

window(VideoMode( (800,600) , "Test") ); //line 22
```

How ever this appears to be incorrect.  As i get this error:

`main.cpp(22): error C2228: left of '.VideoMode' must have class/struct/union`

What am doing wrong here?

Comment: There are a couple of problems with the code you posted: The first is that you are using a pointer as a function; The second is that nowhere is there a dot `.` (like in `.VideoMode`). The error message _should_ have a file-name and line-number, please post _that_ line.

Comment: The line in question is `window(VideoMode( (800,600) , "Test") ); `

Comment: Also, the expression `800,600` evaluates the expression on both sides of the comma, but returns the result of the expression on the right side of the comma.

Comment: According to the syntax the resolution has to be in their own brackets on the first inputs..

Comment: @Dave No, I'm pretty sure that there's something wrong with the resolution argument. As Joachim says, the constructor, as written, will only see the `600`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe I've totally misunderstood the question, but why do you have the pointer defined in *both* the header and the source file? Seems to me you should do the following:

In *globals.h*

```
extern sf::RenderWindow *window;
```

In *globals.cpp*

```
sf::RenderWindow *window;
```

In *main.cpp*

```
window = new sf::RenderWindow( sf::VideoMode(800,600), "Test" );
```

And don't forget to `delete` window once you're done with it.

---

Also, I strongly urge you to replace the global pointer with

```
std::unique_ptr<sf::RenderWindow> window;
```

and initialize it as

```
window( new sf::RenderWindow( sf::VideoMode(800,600), "Test" ) );
```

Now you don't need to worry about `delete`ing it!

Comment: May i ask why i need to use `new` and not just `window = sf::` ?

Comment: @Dave That won't compile because `sf::RenderWindow( ... )` returns an object of type `sf::RenderWindow` and you need a *pointer* to that type instead. Using `new` will give you a pointer that persists until you call `delete` on it.

Comment: Okay, i tried your method and i seem to get `main.cpp(22): error C3861: 'VideoMode': identifier not found`

Comment: @Dave I don't know SFML, so I can't help you with its types. Maybe you need to qualify `VideoMode` with `sf::`?

Comment: Yeh tried that then i get `error C2665: 'sf::VideoMode::VideoMode' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types`

Comment: You probably want `sf::VideoMode(800, 600)`

Comment: @Dave Just looked up an example. You have parentheses in the wrong place. It needs to be `window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Test");` Updated the answer also with the correct syntax.

Comment: Ok so this `window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600) , "Test") ;` gives me `term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments`

Comment: @Dave Sorry, the syntax in the comment is incorrect, I copied it out of an example that wasn't using a pointer. It's too late to edit it now, but look at the answer. You need to use `new` to allocate an `sf::RenderWindow` object since `window` is a pointer type.

Comment: @Praetorian it seems the only way i can do it is like this `sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600) , "Test") ;` it built with no errors that way but is that still assigning as global ?

Comment: @Dave No, that's creating a `window` object local to `main`. The `new` syntax posted above should work. Note that the initialization needs to be performed *within* `main` (or some function called from `main`)

Comment: Hmm strange, it accepts it but has no members so `window.IsOpen();` is no longer a valid thing.

Comment: @Dave That's because `window` is a _pointer_ so you have to use `window->IsOpen()`

Answer (score 3):

Looking at e.g. [this tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/window-window.php) it seems that the `VideoMode` constructor takes three arguments: Two for the resolution and one for the bitmap depth (but the depth have a default value).

You should create the window like this:

```
window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Test");
```

Comment: [Seems](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1VideoMode.php) the bitmap depth argument has a default value.